# TFS stop backup plan

Tags: tfs, backup

I can't find a way to stop/remove a tfs 2010 backup plan, in the admin panel I can only recreate backup but not remove an existing one. I need to do that because I've migrated my sources on git, but I don't want to uninstall tfs, to keep history of the my sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new Backup plan and make the trigger "Manual Backup Only", and don't trigger the backup anytime; you trigger the backup by click backup now in the backup section screen.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than trying to manage this through the TFS Admin Console, you can simply stop the back-ups directly in the Task Scheduler (or Scheduled Tasks control panel item for pre-vista OS's).

When you create the backup plan in the Admin Console, it creates standard system scheduled tasks on your machine, which can then simply be disabled in the Task Scheduler Admin Tool on the machine.